# Topologically speaking, how is the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| y = 0\}$ related to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Topologically speaking, how is the set $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| y= 0\}$ related to $B = \mathbb{R}$

I am curious if there is some formal way to relate the topological properties of  $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| y= 0\}$ related to $\mathbb{R}$, say via some continuous bijective map. Also, how to map open sets from $A$ to $B$

Comment: The $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the subspace topology, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

Comment: To add on to @ArturoMagidin's comment, one can use the inclusion map from $B$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ to show that $B$ and $i(B) = A$ are homeomorphic, where $i$ is the inclusion map. This is the map you want to use to map open sets between the two spaces.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Thanks. Suppose I had a set $C$ (say $\{(x,y)|x+y = 1\}$) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the usual topology generated by open balls. If I map $C$ to $A$ (say via a continuous function), am I guaranteed to have that $A$ is equipped with the subspace topology? Or $A$ still has the usual topology?

Comment: $A$ has the subspace topology regardless of what you map to it. When you talk about "mapping via a continuous function" you must *already* have a topology in mind for both $C$ and $A$, otherwise you can't even talk about "continuous function". If you don't specify a different topology for $A$, then it is usually assumed that $A$ has the "usual" topology, which in this case is the subspace topology (so it is unclear why you distinguish between "subspace topology" and "usual topology". What do *you* think the "usual topology" is?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$, the $x$-axis, is a topological copy inside $\Bbb R^2$ (even an isometric one) of $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology. The obvious homeomorphism to see this is $f: \Bbb R \to A; f(x)=(x,0)$ which is even an isometry ($d((x,0),(x',0)) = |x-x'|$ when $d$ is the Euclidean distance on $\Bbb R^2$ (but also when $d$ is the supremum distance or the taxi-cab metric). So not only topological properties of $A$ and $\Bbb R$ are the same ((path-)connectedness, local compactness, local connectedness etc.) but also metric properties (completeness, e.g.).